# Jacinto6 board with Android: how to build a portrait firmware?

Tags: android, texas-instruments, android-hardware, android-firmware

I'm developing a custom Android firmware for the Jacinto6 board (dra7xx). By default the board is landscape (800x480).

I need to develop a portrait version of the firmware so that:

- when flashing the firmware, in recovery, the board can be handled vertically (480x800)
- when transitioning between bootanimation (landscape) and launcher (portrait) there's no rotation artifact

I already tried to set the "PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTICS" to "phone" and hardcode "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT" into various framework classes (WindowManager, ActivityManagerService, PhoneWindowManager, etc.)

Do you have any solution for this?

Thanks!